# Format DataTable Column for Percent

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a Gridview

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTrades" GridLines="None" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

And I am trying to format the first column into a percentage including the '%'. However, I can't access the column by name. I want to do this from the code-behind and not use a boundfield in the aspx page.

```
DataTable dt = SOME METHOD TO FILL UP THE DATATABLE;
gvTrades.DataSource = dt;
gvTrades.DataBind();
```

This is kind of what I'm trying to do:

```
gvTrades.Columns["MyColumnName"].Text = {0:P};
```

Comment: What does your value look like? Do you only need to append a percent symbol to the end? Or does something like 0.776 need to become 77.6%?

Comment: The number is a whole number '77' or '3'. I would need it to be 77% or 3%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with hardcoding the column index, you could just simply do this in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
    ID="gvTrades" 
    GridLines="None" 
    CellPadding="0" 
    CellSpacing="0" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    OnRowDataBound="gvTrades_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

```
protected void gvTrades_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = String.Format("{0}%", e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
    }
}
```

If not, you can loop each cell of the `HeaderRow` looking for a specific column name. Once you find the correct column, you have the index you need. This would be better done in the GridView `DataBound` method so that you are not having to loop all the header cells for every single row.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
    ID="gvTrades" 
    GridLines="None" 
    CellPadding="0" 
    CellSpacing="0" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    OnDataBound="gvTrades_DataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

```
protected void gvTrades_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int myIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataControlFieldHeaderCell headerCell in gvTrades.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        if (headerCell.Text == "MyColumnName")
            break;

        myIndex++;
    }

    if (myIndex <= gvTrades.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTrades.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[myIndex].Text = String.Format("{0}%", row.Cells[myIndex].Text);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to reference the column specially by name instead of index? I'm afraid the Index may changed based up on changes to the Stored Procedure that populates the datatable

Comment: @Firemarble, see my edit. That should do what you're looking for.

Comment: I see what you're doing but, when it is ran, it breaks on gvTrades.HeaderRow.Cells with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: So is it the `HeaderRow` that is null? If so, are you sure there is data in the GridView? Are you sure you are using the `DataBound` event of the GridView?

Comment: There is data in the gridview. That part works fine, I even see the column headers. OnRowDataBound="gvTrades_DataBound" is on my GridView. When I inspect the variable at the breakpoint, it shows HeaderRow as null.

Comment: Make sure you use `OnDataBound` instead of `OnRowDataBound`.

Comment: OnDataBound is unable to locate the {gvTrades_DataBound} it only see's Page_Load @j.f.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying. You tried `OnDataBound="gvTrades_DataBound"`?.

Comment: gbTrades_DataBound is not found when using OnDataBound